# Check if modulo of a number exists in a tuple

Tags: python

I'm trying to check modulo of a number against a tuple of numbers, if the modulo is equals to one of the values in the tuple I want to return True else return False.

This is what I had tried so far:

```
def check(y):
    k = (2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 29)
    for i in range(0, len(k)):
        if k[i] == y % 30:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def main():
    print(check(1439))

main()
```

It always returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is always returning false as only first item is checked. If first item is a match then it will return true. For example, if `y` is 32 then it will return true. You need to return false after checking all values, i.e. outside of for loop. Or a better solution is to use `in` operator.

```
def check(y):
    k = (2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 29)
    return y % 30 in k
```

Answer (score 2):

It always returns false because this code:

```
for i in range(0, len(k)):
    if k[i] == y % 30:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

returns true or false based only on the *first* item in the array, because it returns in *both* possible code paths. Either `k[0] == y % 30` and it returns true, or `k[0] != y % 30` and it returns false.

If you want to use this loop-based solution, you need to check *every* item in the array, returning true immediately if it matches, otherwise returning false *only* after the list is exhausted, something like (using the `for n in k` variant of the loop since the index is irrelevant here):

```
for n in k:
    if n == y % 30:
        return True
return False
```

The full program is thus:

```
def check(y):
    k = (2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 29)
    for n in k:
        if n == y % 30:
            return True
    return False

def main():
    print(check(1439))
    print(check(36))

main()
```

with the first call producing true as `1439 % 30 == 29` (in the list) but the second giving false because `36 % 30 == 6` (not in the list).

Of course, there's a far more Pythonic way to achieve this:

```
def check(y):
    k = (2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 29)
    return any (x == y % 30 for x in k)
```

That basically finds any element in `k` for which that element is equal to `y % 30`. See [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) for more information on the Python `any` operation, and you'll see instantly the equivalent code given is remarkably similar to your loop:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

But, of course, it turns out to be unnecessary to use `any` in this particular case as `y % 30` is effectively a *fixed* value in the context of searching through the list. Instead, you can opt for the much simpler:

```
def check(y):
    k = (2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 29)
    return (y % 30) in k
```

leaving the `any` variant for more complex comparisons not easily doable, such as only checking even numbers from the list:

```
def check(y):
    k = (2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 29)
    return any (x == y % 30 for x in k if x % 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a generator expression inside `any()`:

```py
def check(y):
  return any(n == y % 30 for n in k)
```

This builds an iterator of booleans that is true for all elements of k that are divisors of `y`.

Comment: I think that should be `==` rather than `=`, yes?

Comment: @paxdiablo Yep. Had Ada on the brain and didn't switch back to Python.